# ヘルプセンターのメタに関する説明に違和感がある

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターの[「メタ」とは？どのように機能しますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)には、メタ スタック・オーバーフローについて以下のように書かれています。ここでは、「ユーザーが スタック・オーバーフロー 自体ではなく」と書かれていますが、これは「ユーザーがプログラミング自体ではなく」の誤りだと思います。

> ### 「メタ」とは？どのように機能しますか？
>
> メタ スタック・オーバーフロー は、このサイト内で、ユーザーが スタック・オーバーフロー 自体ではなく スタック・オーバーフロー の仕組みとポリシーに関するディスカッションを行うところです。

原文では、以下のように書かれています。

> ### What is "meta"? How does it work?
>
> Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow rather than discussing programming itself.

Comment: 私が現在の日本語訳を見ずに訳してみた結果「メタ・スタックオーバーフローはこのサイトの一部であり、ユーザがプログラミングそのものについての議論ではなく、スタックオーバーフローの機能や方針について議論するための場所です。」これが良訳かどうかは置いといて、「ユーザーがプログラミング自体ではなく」の部分は指摘されたとおりの誤訳でしょうね。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

少し遅くなってしまいましたが、ヘルプセンター記事のアップデートが完了しましたのでお知らせ致します。レビューありがとうございました！

[image: whats meta]

---

改善前：

> ### 「メタ」とは？どのように機能しますか？
>
> メタ スタック・オーバーフロー は、このサイト内で、ユーザーが スタック・オーバーフロー 自体ではなく スタック・オーバーフロー の仕組みとポリシーに関するディスカッションを行うところです。ノイズを減らし、このサイトがどのように機能するのか、その理由などを質問するために十分なスペースを提供するために、メインの Q&A からは分離されています。メタの目的は以下の通りです。
>
> - このウェブサイトどのように機能するのかについて質問する
> - コミュニティの質問をする
> - バグの投稿
> - 改善の推奨
> - 新機能の提案

改善後：

> ### 「メタ」とは？どのように機能しますか？
>
> スタック・オーバーフローの**メタ**とは、プログラミングについての議論ではなく、スタック・オーバーフロー**自体**の使い方や方針についてユーザーが議論するための場所です。ノイズを減らすためにメインサイトのQ&Aとは分離されています。メタで扱う主な話題は以下の通りです。
>
> - 当サイトがどのように機能するか質問する
> - コミュニティについて質問する
> - バグの投稿
> - 改善の推奨
> - 新機能の提案

Comment: "そのもの(≒自体)" は「プログラミングそのもの」とするより「スタック・オーバーフロー」にかけた方が自然かなと思い編集してみました。